# MessageBox.Show is not displaying properly in Console Application

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application

I am using WPF System.Window.MessageBox in my console application. It has the parameters as mentioned below.

```
MessageBox.Show(this, "Message", "HeaderCaption", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
```

When I ran this code inside WPF application, it is displaying properly. Since WPF form is inherited from Window class I just used "this" keyword at the first argument as owner window.

The problem is, when I ran the same notification in console application, I just replaced the "this" keyword with Window object.

```
MessageBox.Show(window, "Message", "HeaderCaption", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
```

but the message box is not displaying properly.

Here mentioned my code,

```
   public static Window window = null;
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(StartWpfWindows);
        thread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();

        // This is kinda shoddy, but the thread needs some time 
        // before we can invoke anything on the dispatcher
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);


        // Show something to the user without waiting for a result
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
        MessageBox.Show(window, "Message", "HeaderCaption", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

        }), null);


        System.Console.ReadLine();

        // This doesn't really seem necessary 
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
    }

   private static void StartWpfWindows()
   {
        window = new Window();
        window.Height = 200;
        window.Width = 350;           
        Application app = new Application();
        app.Run(window);
    }
```

[image]

Here in the image the information icon is displaying with large size and header and notification message text are displaying in different location. This message box is occupied entire size of Main Window. How can I resolve this issue? I just want to correct the display of the MessageBox.

Comment: Looks completely correctly on my box.

Comment: And why do you need the window ? Just do it without the window: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox.show?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_MessageBox_Show_System_String_System_String_System_Windows_MessageBoxButton_System_Windows_MessageBoxImage_

Comment: Please, please, please: **do not** show message boxes in a console app!

Comment: @dymanoid : In my requirement I have to display the Message box from a stand alone static class. Which is not UI based application and which will not inherit any Form , Window. Hence I am checking the feasibility in Console Application.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada: Even If we don't input window as owner also , it is not not displaying properly.

Comment: Then it's even worse! Please don't show message boxes by classes that have nothing to do with UI! A message box *is* UI. You violate at least the SRP and many architecture principles.